# Python - Generate binary list with itertools

Tags: python, list, binary, python-itertools

I want to generate the following output:

[11000] all combinations with these numbers, but no doubles

```
   [11000]
   [01100]
   [00110]
   [00011]
   [10100]
   .
   .
   .
```

But I cannot figure out how to do that. In my problem the list has 365 values with about 20 ones.

Comment: Please post your existing code and describe the specific problem.

Comment: Hm this problem boils down to "n choose r", in your case "365 choose 20". That means there are 4.3E32 possible combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 365 possible positions to place 20 ones. So one way to approach this is making all 20-length combinations of the 365 positions.

An example of how that could look like in code:

```
from itertools import combinations

n = 365
r = 20

for indexes in combinations(range(n), r):
    base = [0]*n
    for i in indexes:
        base[i] = 1
    print(base)
```

Since this is a "n choose r" problem, you'll have lots of possible combinations! To calculate how many, use: n! / (r!(n-r)!) = 365! / (20!(365-20)!) = 426112827338828179808453831565930.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
for item in itertools.permutations('11000'):
    print ''.join(item)
```

Comment: This won't do, it will print doubles that the OP doesn't (seem to) want. For an easy fix you could throw the permutations in a set, but the problem is `itertools.permutations` will generate 365! = 2.5E778 items...

Comment: Exactly, that is the problem I am having.

Comment: And your code generates doubles. To filter them out is also not that good, because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that you only get unique strings:

```
from itertools import filterfalse, permutations # ifilterfalse in 2.x  

def unique_permutations(s):
    seen = set()
    for p in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, permutations(s)):
        seen.add(p)
        yield "".join(p)
```

I get 10 output values for `len(s) == 5`:

```
['11000', '10100', '10010', '10001', '01100', 
 '01010', '01001', '00110', '00101', '00011']
```

The generator makes it more efficient than building the list up front, and it only `join`s what it needs to, but you will still be discarding a lot of the permutations.